# Cat 5 Terminal Wiring

Tags: router, modem, cable, wiring

I bought a house where most of the rooms (including my office) have been wired in with cat5 cable and they all run to the terminal block seen in the attached pics which is in the basement. Yesterday I had fiber installed and the tech punched in right by this terminal and set up the modem.

I have a mesh router with two points to cover the house and I'd prefer to keep the router in my office with the points upstairs and downstairs. So basically what I'm trying to do is go from the modem he installed in the basement to my office via the cat5 and then plug my router into the jack in my office in order to connect it to the modem.

So my question is - given this setup, how would I do that? I don't believe I can just go from the modem to this terminal block can I as it'd be connecting it to every room, right? Is there like an 'uplink' section on the block or anything? Do I need to figure out which one of the wires is from the office and disconnect that one from the block to put it straight into the modem so there's a direct connection?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 4]

Comment: Start by finding out which of the wires comes from the office. You need to know that no matter how this terminal is wired. It would be easier to maintain in the end if you just crimp an RJ-45 connector onto each of those wires and connect them all to a switch.